# Listing all nilpotent matrices of $\mathcal{A} = \{c_0I+c_1E_1,c_2E_2\mid c_i\in K\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

How to solve the following problem:

> Let $\mathcal{A} = \{c_0I+c_1E_1+c_2E_2\mid c_i\in K\}$, where
>   $I,E_1,E_2\in \mathcal{M}_n(K)$ and $E_1,E_2$ are idempotent
>   orthogonal matrices, that is $E_1^2 = E_1, E_2^2 = E_2$ and
>   $E_1E_2=E_2E_1=O$. $K$ is a field. We also assume that $E_1,E_2\neq O$
>   and $E_1+E_2\neq I$. The set $\{I,E_1,E_2\}$ forms a basis for
>   subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$.
>
> List all nilpotent matrices of $\mathcal{A}$, that is matrices
>   $A\in\mathcal{A}$, such that $A^m=0$ for some $m>0$.

I have tried solving this, but I'm not sure of my solution and want to verify my approach.

Comment: Does $K$ have characteristic $0$, or not necessarily?

Comment: This information is not given in my problem. One thing I forgot to mention: $\mathcal{A}$ is a subalgebra. If it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let 
$$A=c_0I+c_1E_1+c_2E_2$$

Then 
$$A E_1 =(c_0+c_1)E_1$$
$$A E_2 =(c_0+c_2)E_2$$

This shows that $c_0+c_1$ and $c_0+c_2$ are eigenvalues of $A$ with any non-zero column of $E_1$ respectively $E_2$ as eigenvectors.

Now, if $A$ is nilpotent, all its eigenvalues are ....

**Hint 2**
$$(I-E_1-E_2)^2=??$$

Comment: Thank you! =) Excellent. I was on the right track, but I didn't consider about the eigenvalues :)